# Geometric Distribution Application

Tags: probability, statistics

**The questions**
Alice throws a die 12 times then gives it to Bob, Bob throws the die 6 times. They then honestly report that the die landed 3 times on 1. What is the probability that Alice will get 1 on exactly 2 times rolling on 12 times rolling?

**My attempt**
My intepretation for this question is the probability that Alice get the 1st success on 2nd trials. I think this is Geometric distribution, so i have p = 3/12 = 0.25 (probability of sucess).
Applying pmf of geometric distribution, i have
$$(1-0.25)^{2-1}0.25= 0.1875$$

I am not sure if it is correct since i am not confident

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure about my estimate for p as well since the question did not tell me whether it is a fair die or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that a 1 is obtained on exactly $3$ of the $18$ rolls of the die, which gives an experimental probability of obtaining a 1 of 
$$p = \frac{3}{18} = \frac{1}{6}$$
which happens to also be the probability of obtaining a 1 when a fair die is rolled.

We want to find the probability that a 1 is obtained on exactly two of the first twelve rolls.  The [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is used to find the probability that it will take $X$ [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) to obtain the first success for an event with probability $p$, which is not what we need here.  Instead, we want to use the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which gives the probability that exactly $k$ successes will occur in $n$ trials of an experiment if each trial has probability $p$ of success.  The probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials is given by the formula 
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways exactly $k$ successes can occur in $n$ trials, $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, and $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures.

In this problem, $n = 12$ and $k = 2$.  Hence, the probability that exactly two of the twelve rolls that Alice makes result in the outcome 1 is 
$$\Pr(X = 2) = \binom{12}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10}$$

Comment: I am not sure if the question  I have written is clear since I pulled it out from my test and just writing it based on how well I remember how it was like. But what you said that the Binomial distribution gives exactly k successes occur on n trials. In this question I think we only have 1 success on the 2nd trial on total 12 trials. So how k =2? Does it mean we have 2 successes?

Comment: @Tabitha96 If the intended question was "What is the probability that the first 1 was obtained on the second trial?", then we would use the geometric distribution with $p = 1/6$ and $X = 2$.  The desired probability would be $$\Pr(X = 2) = \left(1 - \frac{1}{6}\right)^{2 - 1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) = \frac{5}{36}$$ where $1 - \frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$ is the probability of not getting a 1 on the first trial and $1/6$ is the probability of getting a 1 on the second trial.

Comment: I am sure that the question was given to me did not explicitly said that the first 1 was obtained on the second trial. But if they said ''what is the probability that Alice will get 1 on the second trial on total 12 rolling?'' then these two questions are equivalent and I should follow geometric distribution ? And if the question was like what I have written initially then it is Binomial Distribution as you have answered ? Is my thinking right ?

Comment: @tabitha96 The probability that Alice obtains a 1 on any given trial is $1/6$.  The geometric distribution is used to find the probability that the first success of an event with probability $p$ occurs on the $k$th trial.  That probability is $\Pr(X = k) = (1 - p)^{k - 1}p$, which is what I used to compute the probability that the first 1 occurs in the second trial in my previous comment.  The probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials of an event with probability $p$ is given by the Binomial distribution, which is why I answered your question with the Binomial distribution.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 0):

The probability that Alice will get 1 on exactly 2 times rolling on 12 times rolling.

$\frac{\binom{12}{2}\times5^{10}}{6^{12}}=\frac{66\times5^{10}}{6^{12}}=0.2961$

$\binom{12}{2}\times5^{10}$ is the number of possible outcomes of two ones if rolling a die 12 times

Answer (score 0):

Huh...  I interpret the wording of this question completely differently.  I thought it was asking for this: Conditioned on there being three 1s among the 18 rolls, what is the probability that two of the three belonged to Alice?  The answer to my question is simply ${12 \choose 2} {6 \choose 1} / {18 \choose 3}$.

I know this conflicts with the word "will" in the question...  but other interpretations don't make too much sense either.  E.g. if one ASSUMES the die is fair and six-sided, then the info of there being three 1s on 18 rolls is irrelevant.  Whereas if one does NOT assume the die is fair, and wants to ESTIMATE the probability $p$ of rolling a 1, saying three 1s out of 18 rolls is insufficient without (IMHO) explicitly stating that one should use the obvious estimate (sample mean).